# Loading data from database into web form

Tags: vb.net, webforms, postback, vb.net-2010

I am creating a two step web form.  The first step is the initial creation of an application (like applying for something, not program), and the second step is allowing a user to modify/resubmit this application.

The data from the original application submission is being shuttled off to a database, and is working as intended.  When the user goes to renew their application, the data from the database is supposed to be loaded into the online form allowing for editing/reviewing.  Currently, I know that the data is being brought into the application variables, but the form is not displaying the data that is being loaded.

The form includes textboxes as well as checkbox lists.

I know nothing about postback, and I've only created local webforms where I can create objects (such as a `user` object, but this is not possible due to a pre-compile error.

The language I am using is VB.NET

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit: Code

What starts off the connection:

```
Protected Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    business_name = txtName.Text

    dbConnect()
    dbGet()
    dbDisconnect()
End Sub
```

Database connection strings:

```
Public Sub dbConnect()
    connection = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=greenapplication;Trusted_Connection=True")
    connection.Open()
End Sub

Public Sub dbGet()
    general_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM general WHERE Business_Name = '" & business_name & "';", connection)
    energy_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM energy WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    purchasing_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM purchasing WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    recycling_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM recycling WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    transportation_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM transportation WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    social_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM social WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    waste_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM waste WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    water_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM water WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)

    PostBackTrigger()
    form_load()

End Sub

Public Sub dbDisconnect()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Postback Trigger:

```
Private Sub PostBackTrigger()
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    generalReader = general_read.ExecuteReader
    While generalReader.Read
        AppID = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("ApplicationID"))
        business_name = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Name"))
        website = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Website"))
        description = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Description"))
        contact = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Contact"))
        enter_title = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Title"))
        phone = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Phone"))
        e_mail = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("E_Mail"))
        street = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Street"))
        num_employees = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Num_Employees"))
        own_lease = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Own_Lease"))
        certs = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Certifications"))
        category = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Category"))
    End While
    generalReader.Close()

    energyReader = energy_read.ExecuteReader
    While energyReader.Read
        track_usage = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("usage"))
        develop_strategy = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("policy"))
        perform_audit = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("audit"))
        replace_bulbs = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("lighting"))
        reduce_lighting = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("over_lighting"))
        lighting_controls = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("controls"))
        not_in_use_policy = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("turn_off"))
        energy_star = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("energy_star"))
        weatherize = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("weatherize"))
        program_thermo = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("thermostat"))
        natural_light = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("natural_light"))
        air_quality = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("air"))
        site_assessment = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("renewable_assessment"))
        renewable_power = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("on_site_renewable"))
        HVAC = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("HVAC"))
        renewable_energy = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("renewable_power"))
        energy_programs = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("efficient_enroll"))
        energy_certification = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("efficient_attain"))
        energy_other = energyReader.GetValue(energyReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    energyReader.Close()

    purchasingReader = purchasing_read.ExecuteReader
    While purchasingReader.Read
        sustainable_policy = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("policy"))
        office_paper = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("paper"))
        maintenance = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("maintenance"))
        ink_toner_purchase = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("ink_toner"))
        food_container = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("food"))
        office_stuff = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("used_stuffs"))
        unwanted_stuff = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("unwanted_stuffs"))
        green_vendors = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("venders"))
        green_businesses = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("purchase_venders"))
        purchasing_other = purchasingReader.GetValue(purchasingReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    purchasingReader.Close()

    recyclingReader = recycling_read.ExecuteReader
    While recyclingReader.Read
        recycle_stuff = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("law"))
        recycle_batteries = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("batteries"))
        clean_sweep = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("sweep"))
        recycle_banned = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("non_landfill"))
        recycle_pharma = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("pharma"))
        recycle_electronics = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("e_waste"))
        recycle_package = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("packaging"))
        ink_toner_recycle = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("toner_ink"))
        compost = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("compost"))
        recycling_other = recyclingReader.GetValue(recyclingReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    recyclingReader.Close()

    transportationReader = transportation_read.ExecuteReader
    While transportationReader.Read
        teleconference = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("teleconference"))
        non_idling = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("non_idling"))
        flexible_schedule = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("flex"))
        bike_shower = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("bike_shower"))
        space_buy_out = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("public_trans"))
        preferred_parking = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("carpool_hybrid"))
        regular_tune_up = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("tune_ups"))
        hybrid_alternative = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("hybrid_alt"))
        bus_bike_route = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("bus_bike"))
        fuel_efficiencies = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("fuel_efficient"))
        grease_oil = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("grease"))
        transportation_other = transportationReader.GetValue(transportationReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    transportationReader.Close()

    socialReader = social_read.ExecuteReader
    While socialReader.Read
        healthy_environment = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("health"))
        prevention_programs = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("prevention"))
        volunteer = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("volunteer"))
        carbon_footprint = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("carbon"))
        charitable_organizations = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("charity"))
        social_other = socialReader.GetValue(socialReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    socialReader.Close()

    wasteReader = waste_read.ExecuteReader
    While wasteReader.Read
        printing = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("paper"))
        bulk_duplicate_mailing = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("mail"))
        printed_comms = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("marketing"))
        packaging = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("operations"))
        bags_containers = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("containers"))
        track_waste = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("reduction"))
        resuable_products = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("products"))
        waste_other = wasteReader.GetValue(wasteReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    wasteReader.Close()

    waterReader = water_read.ExecuteReader
    While waterReader.Read
        aerators_shut_off = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("aerators"))
        low_flow = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("devices"))
        pre_rinse = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("pre_rinse"))
        leaks = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("leaks"))
        landscaping = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("vegitation"))
        broom = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("broom"))
        sink_water = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("sink_water"))
        storm_water = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("storm_water"))
        water_assessment = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("water_assessment"))
        irrigation = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("irrigation"))
        fertilize = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("fertilize"))
        ice_melt = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("ice_melt"))
        water_other = waterReader.GetValue(waterReader.GetOrdinal("other"))
    End While
    waterReader.Close()
End Sub
```

I've tried using a `Business` object, but that gives me an error in the browser about being pre-compiled, I've also attempted what is seen above, which the best I could describe is postback, but I feel like I missed something.

Edit: Added formLoad() Sub

```
Public Sub form_load()
    txtName.Text = business_name
    txtWebsite.Text = website
    txtDescription.Text = description
    txtContact.Text = contact
    txtTitle.Text = enter_title
    txtPhone.Text = phone
    txtEmail.Text = e_mail
    txtMailing.Text = street
    txtEmployees.Text = num_employees
    ddlOwnRent.SelectedValue = own_lease
    txtCerts.Text = certs

    Select Case category
        Case "Amusement & Entertainment"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Amusement & Entertainment"
        Case "Apartments"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Apartments"
        Case "Automotive"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Automotive"
        Case "Computer, Internet, Telecom"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Computer, Internet, Telecom"
        Case "Construction"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Construction"
        Case "Diversified"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Diversified"
        Case "Financial: banks & credit unions"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Financial: banks & credit unions"
        Case "Health Care"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Health Care"
        Case "Hotel / Motel"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Hotel / Motel"
        Case "Insurance"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Insurance"
        Case "Manufacturing"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Manufacturing"
        Case "Professional"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Professional"
        Case "Public Utilites"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Public Utilites"
        Case "Publishers / Printers"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Publishers / Printers"
        Case "Radio / Television"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Radio / Television"
        Case "Real Estate"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Real Estate"
        Case "Retail"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Retail"
        Case "Services"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Services"
        Case "Transportation"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Transportation"
        Case "Wholesale / Distribution"
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Wholesale / Distribution"
        Case Else
            rblCategory.SelectedValue = "Other"
            txtOther.Visible = True
            txtOther.Text = category
    End Select

    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = track_usage
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = develop_strategy
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = perform_audit
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = replace_bulbs
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = reduce_lighting
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = lighting_controls
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = not_in_use_policy
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = energy_star
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(9).Selected = weatherize
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(10).Selected = program_thermo
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(11).Selected = natural_light
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(12).Selected = air_quality
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(13).Selected = site_assessment
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(14).Selected = renewable_power
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(15).Selected = HVAC
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(16).Selected = renewable_energy
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(17).Selected = energy_programs
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(18).Selected = energy_certification
    cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(19).Selected = energy_other

    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = sustainable_policy
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = office_paper
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = maintenance
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = ink_toner_purchase
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = food_container
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = office_stuff
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = unwanted_stuff
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = green_vendors
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(9).Selected = green_businesses
    cblPurchasing.Items.FindByValue(10).Selected = purchasing_other

    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = recycle_stuff
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = recycle_batteries
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = clean_sweep
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = recycle_banned
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = recycle_pharma
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = recycle_electronics
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = recycle_package
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = ink_toner_recycle
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(9).Selected = compost
    cblRecycling.Items.FindByValue(10).Selected = recycling_other

    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = teleconference
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = non_idling
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = flexible_schedule
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = bike_shower
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = space_buy_out
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = preferred_parking
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = regular_tune_up
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = hybrid_alternative
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(9).Selected = bus_bike_route
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(10).Selected = fuel_efficiencies
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(11).Selected = grease_oil
    cblTransportation.Items.FindByValue(12).Selected = transportation_other

    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = healthy_environment
    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = prevention_programs
    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = volunteer
    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = carbon_footprint
    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = charitable_organizations
    cblSocial.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = social_other

    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = printing
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = bulk_duplicate_mailing
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = printed_comms
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = packaging
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = bags_containers
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = track_waste
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = resuable_products
    cblWaste.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = waste_other

    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = aerators_shut_off
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(2).Selected = low_flow
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(3).Selected = pre_rinse
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(4).Selected = leaks
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = landscaping
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(6).Selected = broom
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(7).Selected = sink_water
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(8).Selected = storm_water
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(9).Selected = water_assessment
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(10).Selected = irrigation
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(11).Selected = fertilize
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(12).Selected = ice_melt
    cblWater.Items.FindByValue(13).Selected = water_other
End Sub
```

Comment: @Oybek What code would you like to see?

Comment: The way you grab the data, code that binds to the Repeater/GridView/ListView (list control markup), mechanism that takes to the edit page. In short whatever code that fails to do what it should do. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/?)

Comment: Where are you setting the text of components on the screen to the values of the variables you are setting?  i.e., `TxtBusinessName.Text = business_name`.

Answer (score 0):

AppID is not populated until you call PostBackTrigger()

```
Public Sub dbGet()
    general_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM general WHERE Business_Name = '" & business_name & "';", connection)

    GetGeneralData()

    energy_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM energy WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    purchasing_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM purchasing WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    recycling_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM recycling WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    transportation_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM transportation WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    social_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM social WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    waste_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM waste WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)
    water_read = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM water WHERE ApplicationID = '" & AppID & "';", connection)

    PostBackTrigger()
    form_load()

End Sub
```

New Function to get your General Data First

```
Private Sub GetGeneralData()
    generalReader = general_read.ExecuteReader
    While generalReader.Read
        AppID = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("ApplicationID"))
        business_name = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Name"))
        website = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Website"))
        description = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Description"))
        contact = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Contact"))
        enter_title = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Title"))
        phone = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Phone"))
        e_mail = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("E_Mail"))
        street = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Street"))
        num_employees = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Num_Employees"))
        own_lease = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Own_Lease"))
        certs = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Certifications"))
        category = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Category"))
    End While
    generalReader.Close()

End Sub
```

This application is going to be really heavy on memory using this many variables. You really should set your fields at the same time as reading.

```
Private Sub GetGeneralData()
    generalReader = general_read.ExecuteReader
    While generalReader.Read
        AppID = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("ApplicationID"))
        txtName.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Name"))
        txtWebsite.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Website"))
        txtDescription.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Description"))
        txtContact.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Contact"))
        txtTitle.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Title"))
        txtPhone.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Phone"))
        txtEmail.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("E_Mail"))
        txtMailing.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Street"))
        txtEmployees.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Num_Employees"))
        ddlOwnRent.SelectedValue = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Own_Lease"))
        txtCerts.Text = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Certifications"))
        category = generalReader.GetValue(generalReader.GetOrdinal("Business_Category"))
    End While
    generalReader.Close()

End Sub
```